# How efficient the power usage using dedicated graphic card on laptop?

Tags: laptop

I am looking for a laptop with >= 13 inches full HD resolution screen, integrated graphic card and at least 4GB RAM (or upgradable). I hardly found one without dedicated graphic card. I have no significant reason to buy one with dedicated graphic card. Since there is only one model currently found that fit my requirement, I am considering laptops with dedicated graphic card. However, I am concerned about battery.

Is my concern valid?

Comment: There are a lot of laptops that use Intel HD graphics, which is integrated graphics. What site were you searching on?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (hardware shopping). Please read [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0):

The battery consumption will mainly depend on which graphic intensive work you would do. Such as playing games or using design software such as CAD,etc. Every laptop/PC **will** come with a dedicated graphic card. A graphic card not only delivers means to play games, or perform graphic intensive works, but also is fundamentally required to your screen ON and make your laptop work on the 1080p resolution. Graphic card visually enhance the content on the screen.
As long as you are not running any graphic intensive games or so, the battery wont be much affected for day-to-day purposes.